# Reading from pipe goes wrong

Tags: c, process, pipe, garbage

I want to read the integer from the pipe and then print it, but everytime it prints garbage value. Someone that can help me out?

```
int main()
{
    int pid1 = fork();

    int fd1[2];
    pipe(fd1);

    if (pid1 == 0) // Child process
    {
        int x;
        close(fd1[1]);
        read(fd1[0], &x, sizeof(int));
        printf("I'm the First Child and I received: %d\n", x);   // <--- Here it prints garbage value
        close(fd1[0]);
    }

    else // Parent process
    {
        int x = 5;
        close(fd1[0]);
        write(fd1[1], &x, sizeof(int));
        close(fd1[1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: You do things in the wrong order: You should fork a new process *after* creating the pipe. Otherwise each process will create their own set of pipes, each unknown to the other process.

Comment: Also, *always* check for errors. You must check what `read` or `write` returns. Also remember that (however unlikely) that even `fork` may fail.

Comment: thank you guys, very stupid mistake of me

Comment: @hasan *very stupid mistake of me*  Welcome to writing code, where you can't see your own mistakes but everyone else can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to `fork()` after creating the pipes. So the code looks like this:

```
int main()
{
    int fd1[2];
    pipe(fd1);

    int pid1 = fork();

    if (pid1 == 0) // Child process
    {
        int x;
        close(fd1[1]);
        read(fd1[0], &x, sizeof(int));
        printf("I'm the First Child and I received: %d\n", x); 
        close(fd1[0]);
    }

    else // Parent process
    {
        int x = 5;
        close(fd1[0]);
        write(fd1[1], &x, sizeof(int));
        close(fd1[1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: The answer could be improved by providing some code which shows what changes you made to fix the issue.

Comment: Sure I posted the code